# "The import is empty" errors validating config synchronization after core upgrade

Tags: configuration, 9, upgrading, acquia-cloud

After Drupal 9 upgrade, I can no longer use configuration synchronization to deploy configuration to Acquia Cloud environment:

```
 Import the listed configuration changes? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > >  [error]  Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporterException: There were errors validating the config synchronization.
> This import is empty and if applied would delete all of your configuration, so has been rejected. in Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporter->validate() (line 750 of /mnt/www/html/d9readiness/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/ConfigImporter.php). 
> 
> In ConfigImportCommands.php line 360:
>                                                                                
>   The import failed due to the following reasons:                              
>   This import is empty and if applied would delete all of your configuration,  
>    so has been rejected.                                                       
>                                                                                
>
```

The configuration settings are the same ones that worked before the upgrade:

```
$ grep -Rn '../config/default' .                  
./docroot/sites/default/settings.php:258:// $config_directories['vcs'] = '../config/default';
./docroot/sites/default/settings.php:259:// $config_directories['sync'] = '../config/default';
./docroot/sites/default/settings.php:262:$settings['config_sync_directory'] = '../config/default';
./docroot/sites/default/settings.php:263:$settings['config_vcs_directory'] = '../config/default';
```

My suspicion is that Acquia is overriding my settings somewhere outside of my document root, but I can't quite find it.

Local environment is [Lando](https://docs.lando.dev/config/acquia.html) with the new-ish `acquia` recipe, so perhaps there is some legacy config that comes with `acli` or something.

I'm hoping to install BLT 12 as soon as I deal with the last couple of weird errors in my local; maybe that will help me to fix the config sync issue since it comes with its own configuration overrides.

This may be related to the following error reported by the [Upgrade Status](https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status) module *before* Drupal 9 upgrade:
https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status/issues/3229552#comment-14209685

**UPDATE:**
*via Drupal Slack*

> **mcdruid**  6 hours ago
>
> > My suspicion is that Acquia is overriding my settings somewhere
>
> ...probably not answering your question directly, but you should be able to check any of the settings with e.g.
>
> ```
> $ drush ev 'print_r(\Drupal\Core\Site\Settings::get("config_sync_directory"));'
> ```

I tried this, and indeed it confirms that Acquia is using different configuration which is not in my `settings.php`.

Here is the output from running that command in my local and on Acquia Cloud:

```
$ lando drush ev 'print_r(\Drupal\Core\Site\Settings::get("config_sync_directory"));'     
../config/default%

$ lando drush @dev ev 'print_r(\Drupal\Core\Site\Settings::get("config_sync_directory"));'
Enter passphrase for key '/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa':
/mnt/www/html/d9readiness/docroot/sites/default/files/config_315f86d0f57aa166d80058769033a13b1b4823d0/syncConnection to d9readiness.ssh.devcloud.acquia-sites.com closed.

$ lando drush @test ev 'print_r(\Drupal\Core\Site\Settings::get("config_sync_directory"));'
Enter passphrase for key '/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa': 
/mnt/www/html/d9readiness/docroot/sites/default/files/config_72c878fc6029f4e12c65fa9d1ce2afd4c3a94575/syncConnection to d9readiness.ssh.devcloud.acquia-sites.com closed.
```

This proves that Acquia is overriding my configuration settings.

Just to verify this, I grepped for the Dev configuration directory in my local project and no results were returned:

```
$ grep -Rn 'sites/default/files/config_315f86d0f57aa166d80058769033a13b1b4823d0/sync' .
$
```

In case the public files directory path segment was provided by stream wrapper, variable expansion or string concatenation, I tried again with only the config identifier:

```
$ grep -Rn '315f86d0f57aa166d80058769033a13b1b4823d0' .
$
```

No results again. This config is coming from someplace weird for sure.

Could it be this `require` near the end of `settings.php`?

```php
// On Acquia Cloud, this include file configures Drupal to use the correct
// database in each site environment (Dev, Stage, or Prod). To use this
// settings.php for development on your local workstation, set $db_url
// (Drupal 5 or 6) or $databases (Drupal 7 or 8) as described in comments above.
if (file_exists('/var/www/site-php')) {
  require('/var/www/site-php/d9readiness/d9readiness-settings.inc');
}
```

Note: This config is at least two years old. The project is really not called `d9readiness` (imagine it's called `client-project-name`).

Comment: I've never had an issue with this on Acquia, my guess would be all the things listed in between. BLT, Lando, ACLI... unless you haven't mentioned something here like the sites directory is different on the remote. Are you sure the settings file you have is not git ignored and not making its way through deployment?

Comment: @Kevin I have never had an issue like this before on Acquia either. I haven't implemented BLT yet; first I wanted to make sure I got rid of any obsolete configuration left over from the old project. I just deleted some Acquia Dev Desktop config from the end of `settings.php` and found an old settings include just above that -- see my latest update above. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: @Kevin To answer your direct question: yes, I am sure that  `./docroot/sites/default/settings.php` is not git ignored, and it is making its way through deployment. I see it on Acquia Cloud in the expected location and with the expected contents. The timestamp and `shasum` match those in my local. All this stuff was working fine before Drupal 8 to Drupal 9 in-place upgrade. After reviewing, I do not think I should remove the `settings.inc` include. I'll troubleshoot with per-environment config overrides before I do anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I never was able to figure out where the old D8 project config was coming from, I was able to resolve the problem by explicitly overriding the config at the very end of `settings.php`:

```php
// Replace Acquia Dev Desktop settings (deprecated) with Acquia Cloud environment overrides.
// Note: This is for troubleshooting only; remove this code after configuring BLT 12.
if (isset($_ENV['AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT'])) {
  switch ($_ENV['AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT']) {
    case 'dev':
      // do something on dev
      $settings['config_sync_directory'] = '../config/default';
      $settings['config_vcs_directory'] = '../config/default';
      break;
    case 'test':
      // do something on staging
      $settings['config_sync_directory'] = '../config/default';
      $settings['config_vcs_directory'] = '../config/default';
      break;
    case 'prod':
      // do something on prod
      // Site Factory may require a different value depending
      // on site configuration
      $settings['config_sync_directory'] = '../config/default';
      $settings['config_vcs_directory'] = '../config/default';
      break;
    case 'ra':
      // do something on ra - necessary if a
      // Remote Administration environment is present
      $settings['config_sync_directory'] = '../config/default';
      $settings['config_vcs_directory'] = '../config/default';
      break;
    }
  }
  else {
  // do something for a non-Acquia-hosted application
  // (like a local dev install).
  $settings['config_sync_directory'] = '../config/default';
  $settings['config_vcs_directory'] = '../config/default';
}
```

I have set the same default config for all environments here just to get a basic config sync working again, but my intent is to remove this code after setting up BLT 12. (BLT has its own overrides in different locations, which I don't want to mess up by overriding here.)

Comment: This is pretty odd to me. I have a few D9 sites on Acquia and all I have at the end of settings.php is the one line that changes the config directory. I don't use BLT at all.... so there could be something extra in the mix.

Comment: @Kevin Do you recommend removing the reference to the settings include file?